# Adding to local storage

Tags: jquery, json, local-storage

I am using local storage to add json data as favorites. for some reason when i add more that one favorite it removes the one already in local storage.

```
 $('.favoritesbtn').click(function() {
        var storedbar = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storedBar'));
        var favArray = [];
        favArray.push(storedbar.id, storedbar.barname, storedbar.address, storedbar.description, storedbar.image);
        localStorage.setItem('favourites', JSON.stringify(favArray));
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('favourites'));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the expected behavior.
The local storage is a key-value storage, when you write a data in an already existing key, it is overridden.

In order to add a value, you need to parse the existing value, add an item and write it again.

```
var storedFavs = JSON.parse(localStorage.get('favourites') || '[]');
storedFavs.push(storedbar.id, storedbar.barname, storedbar.address, storedbar.description, storedbar.image);
localStorage.setItem('favourites', JSON.stringify(storedFavs));
```

Answer (score 0):

put the line var favArray = []; out of click event

```
var favArray = []; //here
 $('.favoritesbtn').click(function() {
        var storedbar = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storedBar'));

        favArray.push(storedbar.id, storedbar.barname, storedbar.address, storedbar.description, storedbar.image);
        localStorage.setItem('favourites', JSON.stringify(favArray));
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('favourites'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writting an array of one element, first you need to read in your favourites, add your new element to it then save it back. Try something like this, though your porbably want to add some checks to handle the case where there is no favourties already and use an empty array then etc.

```
    var storedbar = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storedBar'));
    var favArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favourites'));
    favArray.push(storedbar.id, storedbar.barname, storedbar.address, storedbar.description, storedbar.image);
    localStorage.setItem('favourites', JSON.stringify(favArray));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('favourites'));
```